# Run program by user input using a do while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I haven't seem to come across this, hopefully this question hasn't been asked a million times before. I'm having trouble with making a program run again through a do while loop, this would be a very handy piece of code to know but I cant figure it out, any help would be appreciated! This piece of code is just for the purpose of asking this question..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hello1{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s1 = scan.nextLine();

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
    }

    while(s1=="Y");
 }
}
```

Comment: move `s1 = scan.nextLine()` inside of the do-while loop

Comment: Did you search Stackoverflow before posting?

Comment: Yes and I couldn't find any solutions that were represented as simple as this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
String s1 = "Y";
do
{
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
    s1 = scan.nextLine();
}while(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

You don't want to compare `String`'s using `==` you should use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`...

Also you should prompt your user for input each time through the loop.

Comment: How can I make the code so that it prompts each time? that was the results I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your code runs infinitely right now, because `s1` is never reassigned. Try moving `String s1 = scan.nextLine();` into the `do{}` block.

```
String s1 = "Y";
do
{
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
    s1 = scan.nextLine();
}

while(s1=="Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the line of the response after the question
if you need to do that you just have to put the scan.nextline within do after the question ... so

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s1 =""; 
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y/N");//Print
        s1 =scan.nextLine();//Read

    }

    while(s1=="Y");
```

}
}